# can anyone explain how the "->" is implemented in the #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm working on a reference design with this line as a #define

```
#define MEDIA_EXT_STATE "\"adv7611 12-004c\":1 -> \"40080000.tpg\":0[%d]"
```

The sprintf function uses it which is then passed to the `media_parse_setup_links()` function.

```
sprintf(media_formats, MEDIA_EXT_STATE, 1);
ret = media_parse_setup_links(media, media_formats);
```

Comment: It looks like `->` is part of the string literal. The character sequence `\"` is how you escape the quote to include it in the string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro defines `MEDIA_EXT_STATE` as a string literal, similar as

```
#define FOOBAR "foo -> bar"
```

defines `FOOBAR` as the string literal `"foo -> bar"`. Maybe you got confused by the escaped `"`, but thats just like with ordinary string literals:

```
std::cout << "\"123";
```

prints `"123`.

To know what is the meaning of the `->` in the string, you'd have to look into the implementation of `media_parse_setup_links` or read the documentation.

Comment: That's great! thanks for help. I was overthinking it and through it maybe a function that returns with a ->, glad it just a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

It simply translates to:

```
 sprintf(media_formats, "\"adv7611 12-004c\":1 -> \"40080000.tpg\":0[%d]", 1);
```

There is no pointer operation, as it is just part of the string.

When removing the quotes it becomes more obvious:

```
 sprintf(media_formats, "'adv7611 12-004c':1 -> '40080000.tpg':0[%d]", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain how the “->” is implemented

It's just text. It is "implemented" the same way as this:

```
std::string example = "->";
```